# Comparing sets of noisy discontinuous curves / histograms

Tags: group-differences, histogram

I have a dataset composed of measurements of signal intensity along a line; visually they look roughly like the right half of this:

[image]

Each sample is a discontinuous "curve" composed of roughly 600 binned values (pixels), and they are fairly noisy, with lots of little jaggies.

I want to compare a set of samples from a control group with a set from an experimental group, and see if, on average, the distribution maintains the same shape or has a fatter tail (the peak is expected to stay in the same place). By eye they look slightly different, but I would like a formal statistical test of this.

Unfortunately, I have a limited statistics background and I have no idea how to do this. Someone in my group suggested a Kolmogorov–Smirnov test, but first of all I'm not sure if that's appropriate for this type of data (discontinuous) and second of all I can't figure out how to apply it to sets of replicates.

Numerically the data sort-of resembles a histogram, and discussions of comparing histograms often mention the chi-square test, but I don't know how well that would deal with hundreds of bins (and I don't want to change the binning unless it's absolutely necessary), and again I can't figure out how to handle replicates. (Simply averaging them seems like a bad idea; I'd prefer not to lose the sample-to-sample variability.)

Comment: What are the replicates you are referring to? You say your data "resembles a histogram". What exactly are the measurements, are they intensities or counts at a given location along x? You want to know if they have "fatter tails", what does that mean exactly in the context of your data? In the plot on the right ("Plot of Dynamic..."), I don't see what the tails would be.

Comment: "What are the replicates you are referring to?": For each set (control and experimental) we have a number of "curves" (i.e., several biological replicates). "What exactly are the measurements": The measurements are intensities at locations along x, but the intensity should be proportional to the number of fluorescent molecules captured by that pixel, so conceptually they are similar to (messy, arbitrarily scaled) histograms.

Comment: (con't) "Fatter tail": The linked image has highest values at the right and tapers off to the left; in our data the peak shouldn't shift, but we want to test if our exp. group is less concave on the left side, i.e. if there an increase in the proportion of signal towards the midrange. Thanks for your interest :)

Answer (score -1):

If it roughly looks like a histogram you can use KL divergence to measure the differences between them.

I would also recommend you look into using QQ-plots they might give better results than using histograms since you can get different answers on the histogram if you change the number of bins.

Comment: The first recommendation does not seem to address the hypothesis explicitly expressed by the OP in a comment yesterday. In fact, these plots are not histograms at all--they are descriptions of responses versus distance--so trying to treat them as if they were frequency distributions is likely to be mistaken.

Comment: @whuber Then why are you binning data if it is not a histogram? "Each sample is a discontinuous "curve" composed of roughly 600 binned values"

Comment: You seem to confuse binned data with histograms.  The two are completely different concepts.  A histogram represents probabilities, frequencies, or relative frequencies by means of area.  Binned data can arise in practically any circumstance.

Comment: @ ccsv: The data are "binned" because of the pixel resolution of the camera; the pixels are of a discrete size, so the distance from the origin is discontinuous. As I mentioned to gung, the intensity distribution should be roughly proportional to the molecule distribution, so it is conceptually similar to a histogram of # molecules vs. distance.

Comment: @ ccsv, part 2: Thanks for the suggestion of KL divergence, that looks like it might work. Using QQ plots would require a chi-square test for significance, I think?

Comment: @Lebrel I do not think a it requires a chi-square since it is a test for fitting data. A qq plot will give you an alternative representation since binning can give you different result if you change the number of bins.